# Reply received after timeout

Tags: java, amqp, spring-amqp

I want to register two queues listeners for Spring AMQP with the latest Spring version:

```
    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer processingTransactionSaleContainer(ConnectionFactory cf, TransactionElavonSaleListener listener) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
        container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_PROCESSING_SALE);
        container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(listener, "transactionSaleProcess"));
        container.setMessageConverter(new SerializerMessageConverter());
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer processingTransactionAuthorizeContainer(ConnectionFactory cf, TransactionAuthorizeListener listener) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
        container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_PROCESSING_AUTHORIZE);
        container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(listener, "transactionAuthorizeProcess"));
        container.setMessageConverter(new SerializerMessageConverter());
        return container;
    }
```

Listener:

```
@Component
public class TransactionElavonSaleListener {

    public TransactionResponseFactory transactionElavonSaleProcess(TransactionRequestFactory ro) {
        ..... do some heavy network request
        return parseRawSuccessResponse(response);
    }

}
```

When I remove one of the SimpleMessageListenerContainer it's working file but when I use the both methods I get this exception:

```
00:40:14,469 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5) 00:40:14.468 [pool-9-thread-5] WARN  o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate - Reply received after timeout for 1
00:40:14,472 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5) 00:40:14.472 [pool-9-thread-5] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler - Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.
00:40:14,473 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5) org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
00:40:14,473 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1613)
00:40:14,473 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1517)
00:40:14,473 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1440)
00:40:14,473 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1428)
00:40:14,473 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1423)
00:40:14,473 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1372)
00:40:14,473 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.callExecuteListener(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:995)
00:40:14,473 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.handleDelivery(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:955)
00:40:14,474 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
00:40:14,474 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104)
00:40:14,474 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
00:40:14,474 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
00:40:14,478 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
00:40:14,481 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5) Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Reply received after timeout
00:40:14,494 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.onMessage(RabbitTemplate.java:2446)
00:40:14,494 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer.lambda$setMessageListener$1(DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer.java:115)
00:40:14,494 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1514)
00:40:14,494 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   ... 11 common frames omitted
00:40:14,495 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5) 00:40:14.495 [pool-9-thread-5] ERROR o.s.a.r.l.DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer - Failed to invoke listener
00:40:14,495 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5) org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
00:40:14,495 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1613)
00:40:14,495 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1517)
00:40:14,496 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1440)
00:40:14,496 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1428)
00:40:14,496 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1423)
00:40:14,496 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1372)
00:40:14,496 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.callExecuteListener(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:995)
00:40:14,496 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.handleDelivery(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:955)
00:40:14,496 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
00:40:14,496 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104)
00:40:14,496 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
00:40:14,496 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
00:40:14,497 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
00:40:14,497 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5) Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Reply received after timeout
00:40:14,497 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.onMessage(RabbitTemplate.java:2446)
00:40:14,497 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer.lambda$setMessageListener$1(DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer.java:115)
00:40:14,497 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   at deployment.rest_api.war//org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1514)
00:40:14,497 INFO  [stdout] (pool-9-thread-5)   ... 11 common frames omitted
```

Do you know why I get this exception when I have these two methods?

EDITL Defined listeners:

```
    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer processingTransactionElavonSaleContainer(ConnectionFactory cf, TransactionElavonSaleListener listener) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
        container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_PROCESSING_ELAVON_SALE);
        container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(listener, "transactionElavonSaleProcess"));
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer processingTransactionElavonAuthorizeContainer(ConnectionFactory cf, TransactionElavonAuthorizeListener listener) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
        container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_PROCESSING_ELAVON_AUTHORIZE);
        container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(listener, "transactionElavonAuthorizeProcess"));
        return container;
    }
```

...

```
@Component
public class TransactionElavonSaleListener {

    public TransactionResponseFactory transactionElavonSaleProcess(TransactionRequestFactory ro) {

        return new TransactionResponseFactory();
    }
}


@Component
public class TransactionElavonAuthorizeListener {

    public TransactionResponseFactory transactionElavonAuthorizeProcess(TransactionRequestFactory tf) {

        TransactionResponseFactory obj = new TransactionResponseFactory();                  
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Send object:

```
TransactionResponseFactory processingPeply = (TransactionResponseFactory) processingTransactionElavonAuthorizeTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(
        ContextServer.EXCHANGE_PROCESSING, ContextServer.ROUTING_KEY_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION_ELAVON, tf);
    System.out.println("!!!!! Received PROCESSING_TRANSACTION " + processingPeply.getTransaction_id());
```

Comment: You need to show the sending side configuration too.

Comment: Here is the full code: Sender: https://pastebin.com/gjzXCVa6

Comment: Receiver: https://pastebin.com/6iMxmZkk

Comment: @GaryRussell I suspect that into the latest Spring AMQP version I need to update my SimpleMessageListenerContainer. I see that setMessageConverter is deprecated. What SimpleMessageListenerContainer I need to define in order to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observation about your configuration (not relevant to your issue, however)...

- The `declare...` code in your `AmqpAdmin` are not required.

  - you should **never interact with the broker during the bean definition phase** - it's too early.
  - they are not necessary because the admin will find the `Queue` and `Exchange` beans and automatically declare them for you when the connection is first opened.

Yes, that message converter setter is not used for this kind of listener; the message converter should be set on the `MessageListenerAdapter` instead.

However, it gets a `SimpleMessageConverter` by default so that should not be the problem; this converter handles serialized objects as well as plain text.

Now, to your actual issue; adding a second container should not have any affect on the client side; each template gets its own reply container and direct reply-to is used by default so there will be no cross talk between them (which can happen if you use a named reply queue, but that's not the case here).

I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging to figure out what's going on; if you need help analyzing them; post the logs (from both client and server side) and I'll take a look.

**EDIT**

Your bindings are incorrect:

```
@Bean
public Binding bindingQueueProcessingElavonSale() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(new Queue(QUEUE_PROCESSING_ELAVON_SALE, true))
            .to(new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE_PROCESSING)).with(ROUTING_KEY_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION_ELAVON);
}

@Bean
public Binding bindingQueueProcessingElavonAuthorize() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(new Queue(QUEUE_PROCESSING_ELAVON_AUTHORIZE, true))
            .to(new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE_PROCESSING)).with(ROUTING_KEY_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION_ELAVON);
}
```

You are binding both queues to the same exchange with the same routing key - RabbitMQ will send messages with that routing key to both queues, so both listeners will respond.

Comment: Ok, one quick idea: I want to send one big Java object as a message. Am I hitting some timeout limitation? Probably I need to increase some timeout/memory configuration? I added code example of my listener?

Comment: Your reply timeout is 30 seconds; you will get this error if it takes longer than that; again, DEBUG logging should tell all.

Comment: @Garry Russell Sorry for the big delay but I had to finish another bug. Here is the end of the log: https://pastebin.com/z3wRwaiS

Comment: That's not enough log, it just shows the error; you need to follow the log all the way from the outgoing request to this point. For the `Reply received after timeout for 1`, there should be an earlier `Sending message with tag 1`; need to see the entire log including both of those. And you still haven't provided the sending side configuration (which is where this error is coming from). And I can no longer see the sending side configuration - why not edit the question instead?

Comment: the configuration is too big to paste it on the post. Sending site: https://pastebin.com/QygUSB2K

Comment: Here is the full server log: https://www.transfernow.net/files/?utm_source=22bha7q1ig3q&utm_medium=&utm_content=en

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see the issue. Can you give some hint what can be wrong?

Comment: You are receiving 2 replies for each for each message; tag 1 sent `01:11:27,813`, reply `01:11:27,878`; second reply `01:11:28,018` - `Reply received after timeout for 1`. We could change that message to say something like `No waiting thread for 1, either it's timed out, or this reply is otherwise not expected by this container`.

Comment: So the general configuration is correct excluding `....declare...` code in AmqpAdmin but if I understand you correctly target queues are sending together reply? Probably only the proper target queue should be configured to send reply? Interesting why both are sending?

Comment: I have no idea; queues don't "send" anything; something is sending a second reply for each request - look at the DEBUG log on the server side.

Comment: I updated the post. After editing and cutting the code I have a clue. When I comment one of the defined listeners for example `processingTransactionElavonSaleContainer`  the code is working file. Probably I'm missing some configuration?

Comment: Your bindings are incorrect - see my edit. It's generally good practice to examine your queues/bindings using the Admin UI to make sure that they are what you expected to do.

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks like I have a design issue. In my case I have one routing key with exchange witch serves messages to several queues. My goal is to send message to only one queue. Or I need to have unique routing key for every queue?

Comment: Correct. Google "RabbitMQ tutorials" for a quick overview of exchange types and routing.

Comment: I fixed the problem by creating routing key for each queue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Default timeout for `convertSendAndReceive` is 5 seconds. To modify the timeout set property `replyTimeout` of `AmqpTemplate` to bigger value (milliseconds).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#reply-timeout